# MOSFET unwanted turn on

Tags: arduino, capacitor, mosfet, relay, esp8266

Good day everyone, may god save us from this pandemic.

I have below schematic, all of them share the same source and ground.
When 5V applied for a few seconds (e.g a button press) to the MOSFET, relay will be triggered and capacitor charged. Capacitor will keep the MOSFET on until the supply depleted and MOSFET off.

The problem arise as follow:

1. I applied 5V (for a few seconds) to the first MOSFET (choose any MOSFET, e.g. MS1), naturally the MOSFET turn on until capacitor charge depleted.
2. Once MOSFET MS1 turn off, I applied 5V (for a few seconds) to the second MOSFET (choose any MOSFET, e.g. MS2), naturally the MOSFET turn on until capacitor charge depleted. But the previous MOSFET (MS1) turn on too.
3. I try to the next MOSFET, the problem keep repeating, and often 2 MOSFET (MS1 & MS2) triggered when I applied 5V to current MOSFET.
4. The problem not repeating if I wait all MOSFET turn off and add more waiting time for 1 minute or more (waiting all capacitor fully empty).

**Attachments**:

1. [Schematics](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tsl7wtzwANG4iR0PmF2JIx8Y2jiZb83N/view?usp=sharing)
2. [Schematics Simplified](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1RYuND-L5bafxvF22le4e6Hwh7lkrNo/view?usp=sharing)
3. [PCB Layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10jRSsJHk-m8UQOLm5OEt-e06XgfbyIKS/view?usp=sharing)

My questions are:

1. What happen to my MOSFET? Do I need to replace them?
2. How do I prevent previous MOSFET turn on, when other MOSFET triggered once its turn off?

Thank you

### [image: Schematics]

Comment: Your schematic is a bit messy, but I think I follow what's going on. How are these circuits connected together? What is the purpose of SW1?

Comment: Delay purpose, Which capacitor should use

Comment: Okay, you say you have multiple copies of this circuit. How are they connected together? Just a shared ground? Do the relays share a +5V? How are the MOSFETs arranged?

Comment: yes, relays and mosfet share +5V and ground.

Comment: I only see 1 MOSFET. Full circuit please.

Comment: There should be very little interaction between the circuits, even if the MOSFETs were faulty, assuming they share only power and ground. It's not clear how you are applying 5V to the gates. Maybe a photo is in order.

Comment: thx, i'll add more details in attachments.

Comment: I don't understand your circuit diagram.Try draw it simpler.

Comment: Thanks for adding more details. Could you please inline your images, though?  --Anyway, I see you have more complexity than you'd made clear, with some optocouplers/SSRs involved instead of just a FET with each relay. Are you sure it's the FETs that are turning on unexpectedly, and not the SSRs?

Comment: I'm sure it's the FETs, because i unplugged the ESP which trigger the SSRs

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! _"call it MOSFET A"_ Please call it by the designator in your schemtaic and nothing else to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MarcusMuller I sense XY problem.

Comment: Thx @winny, sure I'll make it clear.

Comment: I see several unconnected nets in your layout.   Those are shown by the thin white lines.  Most, but not all, are diagonal so they're quite easy to identify. 
  This includes a pin on every MOSFET.    Unless you're connecting those with flying lead wires after the PCB is assembled, it's pretty clear (to me at least) why your circuit isn't working right.

Comment: Did you design the footprints for the components???   Double-check that you got all the pin-outs right.   Electronics are not forgiving like mechanics sometimes can be - you have to be perfect or your stuff won't work.

Comment: Thx @Kyle B. Looks like I upload wrong pcb picture. You're right it's not forgiving, I found FETs footprints error on my first attempt make this pcb prototype (short circuit when 5V applied to FETs) and now no problem with the footprints (I will change the picture). BTW, I found other FETs problems above, please help me.